# Distance from a velocity time graph where acceleration is not constant

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, projectile, drag

In the following question I calculated the distance with methords actually only applying to constant acceleration. I thought this applicable because the question was asking for an approximation.

[image]

I presumed she opened the parachute at t=13s. In this case she travels 180m from t=10s to t=13s and (using $a=\frac{60-0}{10} = 6$) 300m from t=0 to t=10.

This gave me the answer 480m, exactly 90 away from A and B.

To me the gradient looked constant enough to, for an approximate answer, assume it was constant, however it seems I was wrong.

What method should I have used? (The correct answer is B.)

Comment: It sounds like you already know the answer. You assumed the gradient was constant. It isn't. So is your error positive or negative? Compensate for it, and choose $A$ or $B$ accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The idea would be to indeed use the method you did, but then to realize that your method slightly underestimates the distance because your straight, constant acceleration curve lies strictly below the actual, non-linear curve shown in the plot. So then you would be the option that is a little higher than your estimate, even though the absolute difference is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way of solving this problem:

Since we are dealing with a v/t-diagram, the area under the curve is the total distance traveled and somehow we have to get that. One way would be to have the function $v(t)$ and integrate it, but we can do it without:

In a first approximation, we say that the parachute opened at $t=13\text{ s}$ and we divide the area into two regions: A triangle from $t=0\text{ s}$ to $t=9\text{ s}$ and a rectangle from $t=9\text{ s}$ to $t=13\text{ s}$. This looks like this:

[image]

The first approximation gives us $9\cdot 60 \cdot \frac{1}{2} \text{ m} + 4\cdot 60 \text{ m}=510 \text{ m}$. We see that we have underestimated the area under the graph in the region of the triangle, so it seems reasonable to assume that our $510 \text{ m}$ actually supports answer B, $570 \text{ m}$.

Can we do better? Yes, if we use slightly more advanced tools: The image editing program GIMP has a Histogram feature, which tells you how many pixels there are in an area you have selected. If we carefully trace the graph until the point slightly after $t = 13\text{ s}$, which we assume is the moment the parachute opens, we get
[image]

Now how many meters is one pixel? To find that out, we need to calibrate with a known area. Fortunately, the axes have ticks with associated units, so we know that one small square is $1\text{ s} \cdot 4 \frac{\text{ m}}{\text{ s}} = 4 \text{ m}$.

How many pixels is that? Well, we do another measurement:
[image]

We see that there's a non-negligible amount of pixels the grid adds to our measurement. To somewhat take this into account, we can include the right and bottom grid lines into the calibration, the white area inside equals $196 \text{ px}$, while we measure $225 \text{ px}$.

This way, we arrive at the final result
$$
33614 \text{ px} \cdot \frac{4 \text{ m}}{225 \text{ px}} = 597 \text{ m}
$$

Comment: This is practically a complete solution, and complete solutions are out-of-bounds for this forum.  Please delete your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that displacement = velocity * time.  This means the area under the graph (v * t) = displacement.

To find the exact area under the graph you would need calculus, but since your question seems to be multiple choice this is definitely not needed.  I would divide up the area into sections resembling familiar shapes, and then add up the areas of all the shapes.  For example, at time = 5 you could make a shape that looks very close to a right triangle and then find its area by using 0.5*base*height.

Answer (score 0):

I divided the area into some familiar shapes (namely triangles and rectangles)and I got a total of 560 m.

Answer (score -1):

Here's the thing, take a look at the graph from $t=7$ to $t=10s$. The slope decreases significantly in that region. While this graph might not be the poster child of what I'm getting at, essentially what you have here is something that accelerates to a higher speed and then takes longer to jerk towards a constant velocity. Assuming a constant acceleration only works as a good approximation if there is a region of increasing acceleration to counteract the region of decreasing acceleration at the top of the graph. In this case, there isn't. So what actually happened is that she spent more time at high speeds while her speed was reaching a plateau, whereas you approximated her to have spent equal time at all speeds (not the case).

This question, in fact, gives you the tools to make a reasonable approximation. There's nothing wrong with breaking this line into chunks of constant acceleration; you simply have to know how big the chunk can be. In your case, it's clear that they are giving you the proper chunk size. Each tick in the abscissa defines a region where acceleration can be taken as constant. If I could guess, I'd say this question is meant to lead you into using integrals to make a calculation.

A good approximation for an integral is to multiply some segment in x-values (in this case, a $\Delta t$) by the average y-value for that segment and then sum all those numbers. So what you should do is find the average velocity for each 1 second interval and multiply that by 1 second, then sum it all up.

I'm not going to do the math myself, but if you found a number between A and B your way and the actual velocity before $t=10$ tends more towards higher velocities than with your approximation, it's not surprising that B should be the correct answer.

Answer (score -2):

Here's what I did:  I first tried to get a ballpark answer.  I notice that the average value of $v$ is very roughly 30 m/s, and the duration of the event is 20 s.   This gives me a ballpark distance of 600 m.  There's only one answer that's anywhere near that.